# How i can validate drop down in asp.net to not accept null value

Tags: html, asp.net

Could some one please advice me how i can validate my drop down to not accept null value with submit button. Below is the HTML of drop down.

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Dpd_Dep_Status"   Visible=false  Display="dynamic">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" Display="dynamic"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"  Display="dynamic"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"  Display="dynamic">
</asp:ListItem>
</td>
```

Comment: By null, you mean blank? There are many ways to do so, what you want? JS, jquery? asp.net validators?

Comment: I want to acheive by asp.net vaildation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add a validation group to the dropdown. and then on the validation you can give an initial value of -1.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Dpd_Dep_Status" Visible=false  Display="dynamic">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="--Select--"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y" Display="dynamic"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N" Display="dynamic">
```

The validation

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="--Select--" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Dpd_Dep_Status"
Text="*" ErrorMessage="ErrorMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out but my problem is not solved yet,i have 3 item in drop down list that is yes, no and a blank .if it is blank then it should give a validation error .Is it possible i can apply a check if someone choose blank value then it will show an error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the page where you want to show validation message

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="" ID="RequiredFieldValidator" 
ValidationGroup="VG" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Dpd_Dep_Status" ErrorMessage="Please select a value"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and add `ValidationGroup="VG"` attribute to submit button

e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="VG" Text="Submit"/>
```